# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 - How to stop debugging in other browsers than IE?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, browser

Visual Studio has integrated debugging in IE, when you close IE, it stops debugging, and if you stop debugging, VS closes IE.

I want it to do the same thing with firefox/chrome! (mainly this 2, if is it possible with others, it'll be appreciated!)

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I support this question! I have exactly the same problem - and it is annoying...

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321568/vs2008-debugging-with-firefox-as-default-browser-how-to-make-the-debugger-stop

Comment: greg, post the link as a answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Visual Studio's default browser to Firefox/Chrome. To change this setting, right-click on an aspx file in Solution Explorer and select `Browse With`. Select the desired browser and set it as default.

Comment: Didn't know that--VS otherwise uses the system default browser, which in my case is Firefox. I guess the OP's is IE.

Comment: It does not work with Firefox. The default browser setting is not the OP's problem. The problem is that the debugging session is not closed automatically when you close Firefox (even not if Firefox is default browser). (He explained it in more detail in an comment to another answer but this answer including his comment is deleted now.)

Comment: FF alrealy is the default browser, that's not the problem I'm facing, VS starts FF but don't close it, or if I close the FF, VS don't stop debugging...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to write a macro that opens up ff (or any other browser) with the debugging url.
Then you can control it and close it when the debugging ends.

but i think this task is quite hard to implement.

who mentioned here to simply set the default debug browser is not answering your question at all, b/c it will not be closed...

With Firefox established as your default browser and Firebug installed, you can debug your script in Firefox. Select Tools > Firebug > Open Firebug. The Firefox instance now shows the debugging console. To enable script debugging, click the Console tab, check the Script option, and click the "Apply settings for localhost" option.

Comment: Where do I have to place this macro for it to work?
how to fire it when I press the Debug button or F5 in VS?

Comment: Press Alt+F11 to open the macros window.
All options are under Tools -> Macros menu.
You can write there you own macro, then you can assign a shortkey to it.

Comment: Good, and how this script should look like?

Comment: writing macro scripts is a big issue but rather simple.
you need to know vb.net and then u need to be familiar with vs api to establish this.