# VS2015Community (ASP.net Webapplication): Debugger does not stop himself after closing Edge

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge

created a new web application with one webform for testing. have windows 10, visual studio 2015 community edition.
if i use internet explorer to open/debug the project and just CLOSE the internet explorer, then my debugger in visual studio does stop.
if i use edge to open/debug the project and then CLOSE the edge, my debugger keeps running.

bug? can i reach that the debugger also will stop when closing EDGE?

Comment: The same is true when I debug with Chrome. Considering Edge is more lightweight, my guess is that it wasn't built to be integrated quite as tightly with VS but that's just a guess.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321568/vs2008-debugging-with-firefox-as-default-browser-how-to-make-the-debugger-stop