# Stop debugging in Visual Studio 2015 after the browser is closed

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to set VS 2015 Community to turn off debugging when the browser is closed? I use Edge for debug.

Comment: You will have to use IE if you want that functionality.

Comment: @Cory Thanks, it worked. Why the same functionality is not present in Edge, or other browsers?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892449/vs2015community-asp-net-webapplication-debugger-does-not-stop-himself-after-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edge browser doesn't support this feature, but the IE browser supports it, so if possible, you could use the IE as the default browser.

Since it is a new browser, I help you submit a feature request to the product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16783462-stop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015-after-the-edg

You could add your comment and vote it:)