# Stop debugging Visual Studio 2015 when Edge closes

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, microsoft-edge

There was a previous question asked about debug not stopping automatically when using Chrome browser because chrome was not a Microsoft product / possibly a x64 x86 version issue, is there a setting for Edge i'm missing? 
(when closing IE in the same project debug process stops automatically for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop debugging in Visual Studio 2015 after the browser is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193759/stop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015-after-the-browser-is-closed)

Answer (score 1):

Like this case I answered before, it really doesn't have this feature in the Edge browser:

[Stop debugging in Visual Studio 2015 after the browser is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193759/stop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015-after-the-browser-is-closed)

I submitted a feature request to the product team before:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16783462-stop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015-after-the-edg

You could vote and add the comment.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the feature request, I went over and cast my vote. Thanks again :)

Comment: @FilterMia, Would you please mark it as the answer? So other community members who also want to get this feature could find the feature request easily and help us vote it.

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me, not enough reputation?

Comment: Got it, FilterMia:), I will also pay more attentions to this feature request, maybe the product team could share us more latest information. In addition, you could also add your comments under that feature request. Have a nice day.