# "Stop debugger when browser window is closed" is missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3

I can't seem to find the "stop debugger when browser window is closed" option.

Is this option no longer available in Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3?

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you're running VS2015 and not a more recent version? To my knowledge, VS2022 is compatible is pretty much every project-type that VS2015 supports.

Comment: Also, have you looked under _Tools > Options > Debugging_ instead?

Comment: @Dai I don't have any say in which version of visual studio to use. I looked through Tools > Options > Debugging, it's not there.

Comment: Looks like it was never a feature in the first place in VS2015, _unless_ you're using Internet Explorer (which makes sense, as VS2015 integrated with MSIE's debugging API): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193759/stop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015-after-the-browser-is-closed?rq=3

Comment: Also see here: https://www.itorian.com/2015/07/stop-debugging-stops-iis-express-hence.html

Comment: @Pop You can take a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 was officially released by Microsoft on July 20, 2015(The announcement page is '404' currently). [Visual Studio 2015 update3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs#-visual-studio-2015-update-3) is released on June 27, 2016.

If you use some searching tech such as in Google:

```
"Stop debugger when browser window is closed" + before:2016-7-30
```

You will find nothing related to this, the only two things related to this:

[Stop Debugging stops IIS Express hence application stop running in browser in Visual Studio 2015](https://www.itorian.com/2015/07/stop-debugging-stops-iis-express-hence.html)

[IIS Express immediately shutting down, hence web application stops running, on click 'Stop Debugging' in Visual Studio 2013 IDE](https://www.itorian.com/2013/10/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down.html)

And why these two things come up is because they update the vs2019 content.

**So as Dai mentioned, vs2015 doesn't have this feature.**

Actually, the related update should be integrated since vs 2017. Currently the official document only have content since [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#new-release-icon-1590visual-studio-2017-version-1590). The earlier version was not recorded. The feature should integrate before this version.

You can take a look of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255986/6261890

By the way, because someone's misunderstanding, product team change the name to 'Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops' in Aug 29, 2018.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer here?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Shouldn't I write an answer to this question? . . . If my answer is not good, can you share what you want to say?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Just explain why there doesn't have this feature.